# How to bypass antiforgery token validation on form post in integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, antiforgerytoken

I've an ASP.NET core 2.2 MVC app which exposes a Login page with a basic form (username/password). The controller action is protected by the `AntiForgeryTokenAttribute`, and the hidden `__RequestVerificationToken` is added by MVC.

I'm writing Integration Tests using TestServer and I want to send the form and see if I get 302 status code, but I couldn't find any valid option.

One option I evaluated was to do the GET, extract the __RequestVerificationToken and then submit the tpoken as part of the form. Howerer this won't work as I am missing the cookie (I believe). `TestServer.CreateClient` doesn't support any handler, so I can't add cookies.

Is there a way to test this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so there are two things needed:

1. during the page GET: get the cookie from the Headers and extract the __RequestVerification
2. when submitting the form: add the cookie in the Headers and add __RequestVerification to the model

### 1. GET

You can extract the token using:

```
headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Set-Cookie").Value.First().Split(" ")[0];

// The cookie we are looking for is .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.<unique guid>=<unique guid>
var tokenCookie = cookieContent.Split("=");
var name = tokenCookie[0];
var value = tokenCookie[1];
```

You can extract the __RequestVerification using Nuget package [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) and then doing:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
var tokenValue = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']")
                .Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "value").Select(x => x.Value).First();
```

where `htmlContent` is `HttpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

### 2. POST

When you create the form, add the __RequestVerificationToken:

```
new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    ... your stuff here
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__RequestVerificationToken", token)
        });
}
```

then when sending the request:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endPoint)
{ Content = form };

request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");

await client.SendAsync(request);
```

where `client` is `HttpClient` created using `TestServer.CreateClient`.

Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: Thank you @peval27 . To avoid interfering with the real Content of the request, you can also put the token in the headers instead of creating a `FormUrlEncodedContent` `request.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken",token)`

Answer (score 0):

For a nicer way to get the required tokens and field names without resorting to scraping HTML from pages, I've written up a blog post and same sample code about how you can use Application Parts to achieve the same goal:

1. [Blog post](https://blog.martincostello.com/integration-testing-antiforgery-with-application-parts/)
2. [Sample code](https://github.com/martincostello/antiforgery-testing-application-part)